# keras pre-trained model feed a new input placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that has been trained. like this

```
model_inceptionv3_conv = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in model_inceptionv3_conv.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = model_inceptionv3_conv.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid', name='predictions')(x)
my_model = Model(inputs=model_inceptionv3_conv.input, outputs=predictions)
my_model.fit(...)
```

now I wan't feed a placeholder to this model, but it occured some value have uninitialized. Does this code preds = model(x) will generate a new graph?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 299, 299,
                                          3))
preds = model(x)
sess.run(preds, feed_dict={x: x_val})
```

error
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value batch_normalization_86/moving_mean......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that there is a problem with my own code. I use a wrong sess. I use tensorflow.keras set sess before, but my original code is only based on keras, not tensorflow.keras.

Before

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

After

```
import keras
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

And then, the code as follow can be run.  The uninitialized values are gone.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 299, 299,
                                          3))
preds = model(x)
sess.run(preds, feed_dict={x: x_val})
```

Answer (score 1):

your error is here:

```
preds = my_model(x)
```

it should be:

```
preds = my_model.predict(x)
```

here is a working example:

```
NB_CLASSES = 2
model_inceptionv3_conv = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in model_inceptionv3_conv.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = model_inceptionv3_conv.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
my_model = Model(inputs=model_inceptionv3_conv.input, outputs=predictions)
test_img = np.random.rand(1,299,299,3)
preds = my_model.predict(test_img)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Additionally, I replaced the sigmoid-activation of your output layer to a softmax-activation which makes more sense in a multiclass-scenario ;)

Comment: I know how to do this. but I only wan't to feed a tensor. the input of function my_model.predict() is numpy

Comment: the reason why I feed a tensor is I want to caculate the gradient of network output to x. the formula is d(preds)/d(x)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new placeholder to the graph then you have to follow these steps:-

- Save the weights of your model in one file using `my_model.save()` function
- construct graph again with addition of your placeholder and the load your model weights

Here is a working example -

```
input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 299, 299,3))
model_inceptionv3_conv = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_layer)
for layer in model_inceptionv3_conv.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = model_inceptionv3_conv.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid', name='predictions')(x)
my_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=predictions)

my_model.load_weights('model.h5')
```

now you can use my_model.predict() or sess.run() for prediction like -

```
sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={input_layer: x_val})
```

or

```
my_model.predict(x_val)
```

you can also refer to my GitHub jupyter notebook to see how to add preprocessing steps to your Keras model- https://github.com/CS-savvy/keras-preprocessing-inject/blob/master/keras%20inject.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the gradient d(preds)/d(x), you can use `K.gradients` and wrap up into `K.function`.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

grad = K.gradients(my_model.output, my_model.input)
get_grad = K.function(my_model.input, grad)

test_data = np.random.rand(1,299,299,3)
res_grad = get_grad(test_img)
```